# Stata -- Durbin Watson statistic by company id in a large dataset

Tags: stata

I am trying to run regressions in Stata by `company_id` using a large dataset.  The goal is to get a line for each `company_id` with results of the regression.  I am using the following code that gives me the beta coefficient, std error, adj r-squared and N.  But I also need to include the Durbin Watson statistic and have not been successful doing that so far.  Can someone help?  Thanks.

```
statsby _b _se r2 = e(r2_a) _N, by (company_id) saving($path\SC_results_`i'.dta, replace): regress ret sptr_ret
```

Comment: Cross-posted: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/179923-durbin-watson-statistic-by-company-id-in-a-large-dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small program that combines `regress` and `dwstat` into one command should help. Here's an attempt.

```
capture program drop reg_dw
program reg_dw, rclass
syntax varlist
regress `varlist'
dwstat
return scalar dw=r(dw)
end

webuse invest2,clear
gen index=_n
tsset index
statsby _b _se r2 = e(r2_a) dw=r(dw) _N, by (company) saving(x.dta, replace): reg_dw invest market
use x, clear
tab _eq2_dw
```